# Hover over class affects another element

Tags: html, css, hover

So I am trying to make it so if you hover over the `wrapperleft` class the background color of `cardinfop1` changes, but it does not work for me. What am I doing wrong?

Code and fiddle below:

```
<div id="cardinfop1">
    <div class="cardtitle">Fire Ship</div>
    <img class="cardimage" src="assets/fireshipcard.svg" />
    <div class="carddescription">This card costs 3 gunpowder to use and will deal 5 damage to your opponent.</div>
</div>  


<div id="player1card1wrapper" class="wrapper wrapperleft"><img id="player1card1" class="card player1card"/></div>
<div id="player1card2wrapper" class="wrapper wrapperleft"><img id="player1card2" class="card player1card"/></div>
<div id="player1card3wrapper" class="wrapper wrapperleft"><img id="player1card3" class="card player1card"/></div>
<div id="player1card4wrapper" class="wrapper wrapperleft"><img id="player1card4" class="card player1card"/></div>
<div id="player1card5wrapper" class="wrapper wrapperleft"><img id="player1card5" class="card player1card"/></div>
<div id="player1card6wrapper" class="wrapper wrapperleft"><img id="player1card6" class="card player1card"/></div>
<div id="player1card7wrapper" class="wrapper wrapperleft"><img id="player1card7" class="card player1card"/></div>
<div id="player1card8wrapper" class="wrapper wrapperleft"><img id="player1card8" class="card player1card"/></div>


<style>
.wrapper {
    width: 90px;
    height: 123.75px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    background-color: pink;
}

.wrapperleft {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 18px;
 }

#cardinfop1 {
    width: 350px;
    height: 250px;
    background-color: white;
    margin-left: 126.62px;
}

#wrapperleft:hover ~ #cardinfop1 {
    background-color: green;
}
</style>
```

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u7tYE/8964/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems here:

1. You have to use the class selector: `.wrapperleft`
2. You are using `~` operator wrong

> **The general sibling** combinator is made of the "tilde" (U+007E, ~)
>   character that separates two sequences of simple selectors. The
>   elements represented by the two sequences share the same parent in the
>   document tree and the element represented by the first sequence
>   precedes (not necessarily immediately) the element represented by the
>   second one.

I changed the order of `#cardinfop1` and `.wrapper` elements, and it is working fine. Try the [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u7tYE/8966/)

Comment: Aside from my little class and id selector issue (which was just negligent), it still didn't work. But with you swapping the order of the elements, that is what  I didn't figure out. Thanks very much Chris.

Answer (score 1):

You're pretty close. The `~` is for a general **successor** sibling, meaning it will target a sibling after. Also, you were referencing `#wrapperleft` but you don't have any element with that as an ID attribute. It should be: `.wrapperleft`

Solution: place your cardinfop1 after the elements that initiate the hover:

```
            <div id="player1card2wrapper" class="wrapper wrapperleft"><img id="player1card2" class="card player1card"/></div>
            <div id="player1card3wrapper" class="wrapper wrapperleft"><img id="player1card3" class="card player1card"/></div>
            <div id="player1card4wrapper" class="wrapper wrapperleft"><img id="player1card4" class="card player1card"/></div>
            <div id="player1card5wrapper" class="wrapper wrapperleft"><img id="player1card5" class="card player1card"/></div>
            <div id="player1card6wrapper" class="wrapper wrapperleft"><img id="player1card6" class="card player1card"/></div>
            <div id="player1card7wrapper" class="wrapper wrapperleft"><img id="player1card7" class="card player1card"/></div>
            <div id="player1card8wrapper" class="wrapper wrapperleft"><img id="player1card8" class="card player1card"/></div>
    <div id="cardinfop1">
            <div class="cardtitle">Fire Ship</div>
            <img class="cardimage" src="assets/fireshipcard.svg" />
            <div class="carddescription">This card costs 3 gunpowder to use and will deal 5 damage to your opponent.</div>
            </div>
```

And then fix your CSS as follows:

```
.wrapperleft:hover ~#cardinfop1 {
 background-color: green;
}
```

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sjrmfv56/1/

You would need to fix your CSS positioning a bit though.

Answer (score 0):

You have added #wrapperLeft:hover, when wrapperLeft is a class.
You have used ~ #cardinfop1 where cardinfop1 comes before any wrapperLeft class.

Now as for your requirement, there is no possible way to select a previous element in CSS based on the next element.

But there is one way to do it.

```
<div class="parent">

    <div id="cardinfop1">
        <div class="cardtitle">Fire Ship</div>
        <img class="cardimage" src="assets/fireshipcard.svg" />
        <div class="carddescription">This card costs 3 gunpowder to use and will deal 5 damage to your opponent.</div>
    </div>  


        <div id="player1card1wrapper" class="wrapper wrapperleft">
           <img id="player1card1" class="card player1card"/>
        </div>
        <div id="player1card2wrapper" class="wrapper wrapperleft">
            <img id="player1card2" class="card player1card"/>
        </div>
        <div id="player1card3wrapper" class="wrapper wrapperleft">
            <img id="player1card3" class="card player1card"/>
        </div>
        <div id="player1card4wrapper" class="wrapper wrapperleft">
            <img id="player1card4" class="card player1card"/>
        </div>
        <div id="player1card5wrapper" class="wrapper wrapperleft">
            <img id="player1card5" class="card player1card"/>
        </div>
        <div id="player1card6wrapper" class="wrapper wrapperleft">
            <img id="player1card6" class="card player1card"/>
        </div>
        <div id="player1card7wrapper" class="wrapper wrapperleft">
            <img id="player1card7" class="card player1card"/>
        </div>
        <div id="player1card8wrapper" class="wrapper wrapperleft">
            <img id="player1card8" class="card player1card"/>
        </div>
    </div>
<style>
.parent{
    height:0px
}
.parent #cardinfop1 {
    background-color: white;
}
.parent:hover #cardinfop1 {
    background-color: green;
}
#cardinfop1:hover {
    background-color: white !important;
}
.parent > .wrapperleft:hover{
    background-color: pink;
}

.wrapper {
    width: 90px;
    height: 123.75px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    background-color: pink;
}
.wrapperleft {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 18px;
}

#cardinfop1 {
    width: 350px;
    height: 250px;
    background-color: white;
    margin-left: 126.62px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: No need to swap or position for this solution, but three new CSS classes have been defined and one has been removed